# mpi slots are not available

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

**Machine**

Mac 10.12.6

CPU 3.2 GHz Intel Core i5

RAM 32 GB 1867 MHz DDR3

**ISSUE:**

I have been trying to MPI my code and if I choose more task than 2 I will receive this error by running my code as:

```
$ mpirun -np 4 python loop_mpi.py
```

> There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 4
>   slots that were requested by the application:   python
>
> Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots
>   available for use.

**worth mentioning**:

```
$ sysctl -n hw.physicalcpu
```

4

```
$ sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu
```

4

```
$ ps aux | grep python
58531 100.0  1.9  3139016 626028 s000  R    11:07AM  10:52.89 python script.py
58530   4.8 10.1  5938092 3394584 s000  U    11:07AM   0:54.28 python script.py
58606   0.0  0.0  2432804   1964 s003  S+   11:31AM   0:00.00 grep python
58529   0.0  0.0  2466200  14492 s000  S+   11:07AM   0:00.05 mpirun -np 2 python script.py
```

Comment: I assume you are using Open MPI under the hood. By default, 1 slot = 1 core, which means there are 2 slots on your laptop. You can use the `—use-hwthread-cpus` option to have 1 slot = 1 hyperthread.

Comment: You might also be able to solve this by using "mpirun --oversubscribe ...".

Comment: Hi,
I think oversubscribe puts the same slots in the queue.